# In Camunda , What is the correct way of optimised coding among two options?

Tags: camunda

1. Retrieving userTasks first and then from task, retrive the processInstanceId.
2. First retrieving ProcessInstances and then iterate it with a loop and find usertasks in each process instance.

Please give reason too.

Comment: Is this about rest api? There you can query for user tasks based on processInstanceId. https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/reference/rest/task/get/ What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to only retrieve the UserTasks and display the variables associated with the processInstanceId of that particular task. This is my usecase. Now I have done it but only thing I am not able to retrieve is the processBusinessKey. Can you please suggest how to retrieve the processBusinessKey from the particular task?                                                                                                                         
  List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list();

Comment: Afaik, businessKey is not stored with user tasks out of the box. But you can add it as a variable when task is created.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build a task list you should use the task queries, as you can do the right queries and filters there easily. Process instance id's are part of the result. 
But it would indeed be interesting to understand the use case, what exactly you need the process instance id for.

Comment: I need to only retrieve the UserTasks and display the variables associated with the processInstanceId of that particular task. This is my usecase. Now I have done it but only thing I am not ableto retrieve is the processBusinessKey. Can you please suggest how to retrieve the processBusinessKey from the particular task?                                                                                                                         
  List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list();